# How do I pass the div element outside setup function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to add this to my vue app
https://jsbin.com/yejehog/edit?html,js,console,output

I've added to my code, how do I pass the div id to Sortable.create?
In my console I get error `Uncaught Sortable:` el` must be an HTMLElement, not [object Null]

```js
import { Sortable, Swap } from 'sortablejs/modular/sortable.core.esm';
Sortable.mount(new Swap());

let list = document.getElementById("list")

Sortable.create(list, {
  multiDrag: true,
  selectedClass: "selected"
});
```

```html
 <div id="list" v-for="(item, index) in points.pointList.collection">
<p>{{ item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Tried aswell this

```js
    const clueDiv = ref(null)

  Sortable.mount(new Swap());

    Sortable.create(clueDiv.value, {
      multiDrag: true,
      selectedClass: "selected"
    });
```

```html
    #list(v-for="(item, index) in points.pointList.collection" ref="clueDiv")
```

Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `list` id should be added to the wrapper element that contains the items rendered using v-for then use `onMounted` hook to run init the sortable function :

```
<div id="list" ref="clueDiv">
  <div  v-for="(item, index) in points.pointList.collection">
   <p>{{ item.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and :

```
 const clueDiv = ref(null)

onMounted(()=>{
 Sortable.mount(new Swap());

    Sortable.create(clueDiv.value, {
      multiDrag: true,
      selectedClass: "selected"
    });
})
```

Comment: I am still getting `Uncaught (in promise) Sortable: `el` must be an HTMLElement, not [object Null]` for some reason

Comment: thank you got it fixed, one more question. If I wanted to use http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#filter the filter thing, but I have to provide a class there, how would you do it? Do I need to use ref for this aswell?

Comment: use class based on condition like `<div  v-for="(item, index) in points.pointList.collection" :class="{'filtered':index===2}">` then use .filtered class as mentioned in the example